# AsyncTask inside a AsyncTask's doingBackground method?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I tried to run this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }
            }.execute();
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

`AsyncTask` must be created in the UI thread, but the code runs fine.

I think it is because of a `Handler` inside an `AsyncTask`, so it must be created in a UI thread.

I am confused. Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this in the first place? There is probably a much better way to do it.

Comment: No you can't do like that. The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread

Comment: @jingwei so if it runs ok what is the problem then?

Comment: but some times it will throw exception like Looper.prepare() error

Comment: I just want to know why ... T_T

Comment: Undefined behaviour may look like it does what you want, but it's unlikely you've tested every combination of API version and architecture, so it likely already doesn't do what you want some of the time, and nobody's going to ensure it acts the same from now on. When Google documents an API it tells you what it promises that API will always do. They don't just run lots of tests and make empirical guesses.

Comment: @jingwei remove asynctask code in doinbackground

Comment: okay, i think you are right...

Comment: @Raghunandan AsyncTask should be loaded in UI thread only pre JellyBean. In JB. framework takes care of running AsycTask in UI thread.

Comment: Why are you calling .execute() twice?

Comment: @prijupaul you quoting from the docs. i know that. op hasn't mentioned on what api level he is testing

Comment: @prijupaul and also The task instance must be created on the UI thread.